# Storybook: Unable to get Show code to work

Tags: storybook, storybook-addon, storybook-addon-doc

I get the propTypes to render but not the show code...

This is my `Component.stories.jsx`

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { MoreVertical, Repeat, Trash2, ExternalLink } from 'react-feather';
import { radios } from '@storybook/addon-knobs';
import { withMemoryRouter } from 'utils/wrapper';
import { HORIZONTAL, VERTICAL } from 'data/globals';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import ActionMenu from '.';
import ContainerCenteredStorybook from '../storybook/ContainerCenteredStorybook';

export function ActionMenuExample() {
  [![enter image description here][1]][1]
  return (
    <ContainerCenteredStorybook>
      <>
        <MoreVertical onClick={handleClick} />
        <ActionMenu
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
          anchorOrigin={{
            horizontal: anchorHorizontal,
            vertical: anchorVertical,
          }}
          onClose={handleClose}
          items={items}
          transformOrigin={{
            horizontal: transformHorizontal,
            vertical: transformVertical,
          }}
        />
      </>
    </ContainerCenteredStorybook>
  );
}

ActionMenuExample.storyName = 'Action Menu';

export default {
  component: ActionMenu,
  decorators: [withMemoryRouter],
  title: 'Action Menu',
};
```

[image]

As you can see **No code is available**...
How do I get this to work?